# How do I get sympy to simplify an expression containing sqrt(2)/2?

Tags: sympy

This code:

```
from sympy import *
x = Symbol('x', positive=True)
vp = Symbol('vp', positive=True)
num = integrate( (vp*sin(x))**2, (x, 0, 2*pi))
den = integrate(      1        , (x, 0, 2*pi))
print " num =",num
print " den =",den
vrms = sqrt(num/den)
print "vrms =",vrms
print "simplified vrms = ",simplify(vrms)
```

Returns this:

```
 num = pi*vp**2
 den = 2*pi
vrms = sqrt(2)*vp/2
simplified vrms =  sqrt(2)*vp/2
```

How can I get it to take the last step?  I'd like it return this:

```
vrms = vp/sqrt(2)
```

Comment: Much of the code isn't relevant:  you could just type `x=sqrt(2)/2` and then try to simplify x. Problem is, sqrt(2)/2 is considered a simpler form than 1/sqrt(2).  Entering `x=1/sqrt(2)` will automatically turn it to `sqrt(2)/2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SymPy automatically canonicalizes rational power of rational numbers to a form with positive exponents and reduced powers. Because this happens automatically, it will happen with every such number that appears in any expression, meaning there is no way to make `sqrt(2)/2` result in `1/sqrt(2)`.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like sqrt(2)/2 *is* simpler than 1/sqrt(2).

Thank you, sandwich.

Indeed, much of the code in the example is superfluous.  I was worried that how the symbols were defined and calculated could be relevant.