# Disable automatically rationalizing denominators in sympy

Tags: sympy

Is there any way to stop automatically rationalizing denominators in sympy? I want to get non-rationalizing output 1/sqrt(2) as output of cos(pi/4). Now I get sqrt(2)/2 as output of cos(pi/4).

Comment: Similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37378902/how-do-i-get-sympy-to-simplify-an-expression-containing-sqrt2-2)

Answer (score 1):

Rationalization happens automatically (see [How do I get sympy to simplify an expression containing sqrt(2)/2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37378902/how-do-i-get-sympy-to-simplify-an-expression-containing-sqrt2-2)). You can manually avoid automatic evaluation with `with evaluate(False)`

```
In [39]: with evaluate(False):
   ....:     print(1/sqrt(2))
   ....:
1/(sqrt(2))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I want to get non-rationalizing output as calculation result like cos(pi/4). I think `with evaluate(False)` doesn't work for that. You mean there is not any way for this like disable rationalizing option, right?

Comment: There is not. You would need to write a function that takes a rationalized output (what cos(pi/4) returns) and de-rationalizes it with evaluate=False. I don't know of an existing function that does this.

Comment: I'm sorry for my incompleteness.

Comment: I tried bellow code.
    In [3]: with evaluate(False):
       ...:     print(cos(pi/4))
    cos(pi/4**1)
I want to get de rationalized output 1/sqrt(2) as calculation result of  cos(pi/4). `with evaluate(False):` seems not to calculate anything.

Comment: It won't be that simple, because `cos(pi/4)` is programmed to give the rationalized output (evaluated or no). That's why I said you'd have to write a function to de-rationalize it.

Comment: OK. I understand. It seems I have to give up that problem. Thank you so much.